# Get-ADUser for not exact username

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

The script below lists some user details, it works only in case I've entered the EXACT user name. Is there a method I could use to get results if I type a partial username?
I mean if for example I enter "elibukin" or "eli.buk" instaed of "eli.bukin" witch is the correct username.

```
do {
    Write-Host "Who r we looking for ?        (type EXIT when u done)"
    $User = Read-Host
    Get-ADUser $User -Properties * |
        fl empl*,title, sam*, disp*, mail*, manager*, depa*, giv*, l, last*,
           logon*, when*
} until ($user -eq "exit")
```

Comment: Look at the help for Get-ADUser. Specifically the -Filter parameter.

Comment: You can improve your code by expressing the question with Read-Host: `$User = Read-Host -Prompt "Who r we looking for ?        (type EXIT when u done)"`

Comment: thanX very much guys' i mannaged to handle it by myself :>

Answer (score 5):

I would use -LDAPFilter with ambiguous name resolution (ANR).

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=smith)"
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/1a9177f4-0272-4ab8-aa22-3c3eafd39e4b for more information about ANR.

Comment: +1 for [ANR](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx)

Comment: That link is gone.

Comment: Link has been updated. Works as of 11/12/2023. (Also: A search for "Active Directory LDAP ANR" should get you there pretty quickly as well.)

Answer (score 1):

I have actually worked on a script much like this. I used the -like operator to accommodate partial matches. However, this might give you more than one result.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter ("SamAccountName -like '*$user*'")
```

Or use something of this format to narrow down your result:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter ("SamAccountName -like '*$user*' -and Name -like '*$FirstName*' -and Surname -like '*$Lastname*'")
```

Use `-or` instead of `-and` for a broader result.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. I would recommend using ANR (see my answer) as it does a pretty good job of finding partial match names across a set of different attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fuzzy matching use the parameter `-Filter` with the `-like` operator:

```
do {
  $user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Who are we looking for (type EXIT when done)'
  if ($user -ne 'exit') {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*$User*'" -Properties * |
      Format-List empl*,title, sam*, disp*, mail*, manager*, depa*, giv*, l,
                  last*, logon*, when*
  }
} until ($user -eq "exit")
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use -ldapfilter.  -filter and ambiguous name resolution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_name_resolution).  I had a case where two names were in the givenname, and the email was different from the upn.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "anr -eq 'joe smith'"
```