# Import-Csv then foreach

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV file that contains username and passphrase. I'd like to go through AD and add an e-mail address to this. That way I could then send each user an e-mail informing them of their passphrase.

I'm trying to match the username field found in the CSV file with the `samAccountName`, this is what I have so far, but the problem is some usernames are very, very similar and the `-like` operator isn't a perfect fit. I end up with multiple e-mail addresses (some incorrect) on the same line.

```
$a = Import-Csv .\users_pass.csv |
     Select-Object "User Name", Passphrase |
     Foreach-Object {
         $user = $_
         $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*$($_."User Name")*'" -Properties EmailAddress |
                   select EmailAddress

         New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
             Username = $user."User Name"
             Passphrase = $user.Passphrase
             EmailAddress = $aduser.EmailAddress
         }
     }
```

Comment: For each user, use get-mailbox and pass it the account's UPN, and get the PrimarySMTPAddress

Comment: Why can't you use the `-eq` operator? If the names from the CSV don't match the account names exactly, perhaps [ambiguous name resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34664331/1630171) might help?